# Add new key value pair in Angular Dynamic Form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-dynamic-components

I have a requirement in Angular Dynamic Form to add key-value pair on click of add button.Both key and value should be editable

a)- Key either we can select from master list or it can be a free textbox(if value is not available in master list then autocomplete should be replaced by textbox).

b)- Value should be a textbox.

Also, There should be a nearby save button and delete button along with above fields to either submit it or delete it.

As per current implementation in our project,'key' is always hardcoded and 'value' is editable inside form group.

What should be the best approach to add a new key-value pair in dynamic form?

1- Should we need to create a new form group for adding new row?

2- Utilize the current approach and extend the functionality on it in same form group

Any approach/leads will be most welcome.

Comment: You can refer this http://keepnote.cc/code/reactive-form-key-value-pair-bootstrap-angular-4-5-6-7

Answer (score 0):

1 .On button click create a function that create form group and add to form array in your parent FormGroup

2. For put key values like this

```
  let r=this.fb.group({mvl:"keey",sec:"val"});
```

3. Mark your input readonly to make it non edible

```
foo:FormGroup
constructor(public fb:FormBuilder) {
  this.foo=this.fb.group({
      string  :"",
      number:0,
      common1:this.common,
      common2:this.common,
      multi:this.fb.array([])
    });
}

add()
{
  let r=this.fb.group({mvl:"keey",sec:"val"});
  (this.foo.get("multi") as FormArray).push(r);
}
```

Inside your form put html like this

```
 <div formArrayName="multi">
            <div *ngFor="let el of multiForm;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">

                    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="mvl{{i}}" formControlName="mvl">

                    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="sec{{i}}" formControlName="sec">
            </div>
            <div (click)="add()">add</div>
        </div>
```